# Android Custom font Spannable Typeface Span

Tags: android, textview, typeface, custom-font

I am using Helvetica fonts throughout my application. Currently I am creating the fonts separately from assets. So I have say these three

```
HelveticaNeue = Typeface.createFromAsset(application.getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf");
HelveticaNeueBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(application.getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf");
HelveticaNeueBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(application.getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueBoldItalic.ttf");
```

Everything works great when I use one typeface for one TextView.  However, I need to use a spannable

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("This text should be normal, but this needs to be bold, and normal");    
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("bold"), 5, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

And I want to have part of the string be HeleveticaNeueBold and some be just HelveticaNeue.  I think what is needed is to indicate to Android that the 3 fonts above are actually related so that it can switch them nicely.  Looking for any other way of doing this as well.

Comment: Have you found answer for this question? Please share solution. I also want to use two Helvetica's fonts for ONE TextView ))) Thanks.

Comment: No need of custom typeface.Here is the answer [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font/51378290#51378290)

Answer (score 20):

You are going to want to write a custom TypefaceSpan.  The good news is that they aren't difficult.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("your text");
Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.your_font);
spannableString.setSpan(
    new TypefaceSpan(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL)), 
    0, 4, 
    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

This constructor will replace the previous style of the text, achieving what you want. However, the catch is that it was introduced in API 28.