# How set Spannable object font with custom font

Tags: android, android-fonts, spannable

I have Spannable object which I want to set its font by a custom font I have loaded before.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font_Name.ttf");
Spannable span1 = /*Spannable Item*/;

/// I want to set span1 to have tf font face???
/// Here where I want help.
```

EDIT : 
My problem is that I want to set two different custom fonts for the text view so I am working with the Spannable

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface/17961854#17961854

Comment: @BenjaminDobell A question cannot be a duplicate of an answer. Don't link to your own answer.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This is a late answer but will help others to solve the issue.

### Use the following code:(I'm using Bangla and Tamil font)

```
  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_fonts);  
        txt.setTextSize(30);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Akshar.ttf");
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bangla.ttf");   
        SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("আমারநல்வரவு");
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font2), 0, 4,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 4, 11,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        txt.setText(SS);
```

---

The outcome is:

[image]

---

### CustomTypefaceSpan Class:

```
package my.app;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

private final Typeface newType;

public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}

private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }

    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
}
```

---

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface)

Comment: Nice one - though if you're going to use it with family "", why not remove the family parameter from the constructor altogether and just call super("");

Comment: @imran-rana how can i use `CustomTypefaceSpan` ?

Comment: @Imran Rana, this custom class gives a lint error.     "This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field."

Comment: @Krups Yep this is not going to work if the CustomTypefaceSpan is parcelled and unparcled by the OS.

Comment: Warning: This class implements `Parcelable` but does not provide a `CREATOR` field.

Comment: Can somebody explain what the bitwise operations are doing?

Comment: I have discovered that TextAppearanceSpan works with a custom font defined in a style (i.e. <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/<your_custom_font></item>on API 27 and up, but the font is ignored on anything lower than 27. I had to create a custom view and use this solution in my case.

Answer (score 31):

Create a CustomTypefaceSpan class:

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {

    private final Typeface typeface;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(Typeface typeface) {
        this.typeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, typeface);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, typeface);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Use in the same way as the Android framework spans classes:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_fonts);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Akshar.ttf");
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bangla.ttf");
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder("আমারநல்வரவு");
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan(font2), 0, 4,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan(font), 4, 11,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

This answer is based on Imran Rana's answer but does not extend `TypefaceSpan` and then disable its functionality. `CustomTypefaceSpan` extends `MetricAffectingSpan` directly.

This answer shares a defect with Imran Rana's answer. The span is not parcelled. I.e if you do this (kotlin):

```
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    TextUtils.writeToParcel(spannableStringBuilder, parcel, 0)
    parcel.setDataPosition(0)
    val sequence = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)
    parcel.recycle()
```

Any `CustomTypefaceSpan` objects set on `spannableStringBuilder` will not be marshalled and unmarshalled.

Answer (score 21):

We don't need to use CustomTypefaceSpan. Here is the solution using [StyleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan).

```
/**
* setCustomFontTypeSpan
* @param context
* @param source
* @param startIndex
* @param endIndex
* @param font
* @return
*/
public static SpannableString setCustomFontTypeSpan(Context context, String 
source, int startIndex, int endIndex, int font) {
      final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(source);
      Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, font);
      spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(typeface.getStyle()), 
      startIndex,endIndex,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
return spannableString;
}

String source = "Hello world";
SpannableString string = setCustomFontTypeSpan(context, source, 6, 
source.length(), R.font.open_sans_bold);
textView.setText(string);
```

Comment: StyleSpan is not intended to set the typeFace. As stated in documetation: Span that allows setting the style of the text it's attached to. Possible styles are: Typeface#NORMAL, Typeface#BOLD, Typeface#ITALIC and Typeface#BOLD_ITALIC.
Given code would set span to BOLD, not affecting the typeface

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Roboto, you can set a different TypefaceSpan in the constructor

```
TypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif-medium");

textView.setSpan(typefaceSpan, indexStart, textLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using android KTX `buildSpannable{...}`,

I recommend this one.

```kotlin
inline fun SpannableStringBuilder.font(typeface: Typeface? = null, builderAction: SpannableStringBuilder.() -> Unit) =
    inSpans(StyleSpan(typeface?.style ?: Typeface.DEFAULT.style), builderAction = builderAction)
```

#### Usage

```kotlin
binding.title.text = buildSpannedString {
    color(getColor(R.color.main_mint)) {
        font(getFont(R.font.notosans_medium)) {
            append("colored and typefaced")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Newer, simpler answer for >= API 28

```
val myTypeface = Typeface.create(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.acme), Typeface.NORMAL)
val string = SpannableString("Text with typeface span.")
string.setSpan(TypefaceSpan(myTypeface), 10, 18, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
string.setSpan(TypefaceSpan("monospace"), 19, 22, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

textView.text = string
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to do the same and I found that I need to use a TypefaceSpan. The problem is that the constructor taking a Typeface is only added in API level 28. So the workaround I found is to do the following:

```
val spannable = SpannableString("My String")
spannable.setSpan(object : TypefaceSpan(null) {
    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
        ds.typeface = Typeface.create(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.my_font), Typeface.NORMAL) // To change according to your need
    }
}, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE) // To change according to your need
myTextView.setText(spannable)
```

Answer (score 5):

In kotlin would be:

**First step**, create this class

```
class CustomTypefaceSpan(family: String?, private val newType: Typeface) :
  TypefaceSpan(family) {
  override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
      applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType)
  }

  override fun updateMeasureState(paint: TextPaint) {
      applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType)
  }

  companion object {
      private fun applyCustomTypeFace(paint: Paint, tf: Typeface) {
          val oldStyle: Int
          val old = paint.typeface
          oldStyle = old?.style ?: 0
          val fake = oldStyle and tf.style.inv()
          if (fake and Typeface.BOLD != 0) {
              paint.isFakeBoldText = true
          }
          if (fake and Typeface.ITALIC != 0) {
              paint.textSkewX = -0.25f
          }
          paint.typeface = tf
      }
  }

}
```

**Second step**,

```
    val prefixText = SpannableString("I read and accept ")
    val prefixTextLen = prefixText.length

    prefixText.setSpan(
        CustomTypefaceSpan("", ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.gotham_bold)!!),
        0,
        prefixTextLen,
        0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your `Spannable` to your `TextView` first and then, try to assign the Typeface to your `TextView` with `myTextView.setTypeface(tf)`;

Comment: Further to Serkan's answer, I have written a blog entry which details how to use spans at http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177. It doesn't specifically cover setting typefaces, which is why I haven't posted this as an answer, but it does cover some of the common pitfalls with spans in general.

Comment: But this just sets the typeface on the entire TextView? It's not a span.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example where, str is your full string and boldString is the part you need to make bold.

```
public static SpannableString getTextStyleSpan(String str, String boldString) {

        SpannableString formated = new SpannableString(str);

        int start1 = str.indexOf(boldString);
        int end1 = start1 + colorString1.length();

        formated.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), start1, end1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        return formated;
    }
```