# how to display telugu characters in my android application

Tags: android

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Tikkana.ttf");
System.out.println("8888 "+tf.getStyle());
System.out.println(tf);
yourName.setTypeface(tf);
```

I am using above code but it is not working. The text is displaying like some rectangular boxes.

Comment: this might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font#answer-10741161

Answer (score 0):

Try working with this. http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/localization-using-ttf-files.html