# Multiple font to single textview depending on langugage

Tags: android, fonts, textview, font-face

So at the moment I have textviews with English text and Arabic text and I am doing is applying font depending what language is in the textview , but there are some times when i have both English and Arabic in single text , so how is it possible for me to apply arabic and english font on the same Textview? 
Is it possible that i merge two fonts in one font type , and apply it every where, will that work?

Comment: You may look into `EditText` instead and disable any type of input.

Comment: Using two different fonts (or typefaces) in a single `TextView` can be as easy as building a `Spannable` out of the individual pieces and applying two [`TypefaceSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html)s.

Comment: @SiKni8 is it possible to add multiple fonts in a single edittext?

Comment: @chossen-addict I added an answer for you. The link is also very helpful :)

Comment: @MH Yes you are right but why don't you help others by providing a link to sample usage of `TypeSpans` and reducing further googling. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font/10741161#10741161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

```
String firstString = "AAAAAA: ";
String secondString = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(firstString + secondString);

sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, firstString.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)), firstString.length() + 1,
        firstString.length() + secondString.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(sb);
```

might work

Comment: I meant font , so what you are suggesting that its not possible?
Isnt there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
mBox = new TextView(context);
mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + description + "</small>" + "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + DateAdded + "</small>"));
```

taken from here: **[Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)**