# How to add different font for different language in a TextView in android?

Tags: android, custom-font

I have a `TextView` which contains dynamic text of different languages, for example, *آب آشامیدنی گازدار خوشگوار 500 میلی‌لیتر*. What i want to do is to use two different (custom) font for English and Persian text.

**NB:** Text length is variable. In actual implementation, there is not only `TextView` but also other `View` and lots of `View`.

Comment: You need to provide custom typeface and apply to edittext. Just search for   "android custom font"

Comment: did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989067/multiple-font-to-single-textview-depending-on-langugage)?

Comment: But how I specify a font for a specific language. `View`s may contain multiple language at a time.

Comment: see [this answer too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @mehrdadkhosravi actually text comes from server as a json response and i don't know the exact length of the text and i set data in textview of recyclerview.

Comment: Do you get any information in the JSON regarding the language of the text? Do you know if it's persian or english?

Comment: @user13 No, What i get is only the text. But i know it can be a mix of these two.