# How to can i apply customfontstyle to the middle of textview in android?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have a textview ,that contains different texts that can set dynamically.

different string likes

```
String s1="I am a Good boy";

String s2="I am a Bad` boy";

TextView tvnotificationstype=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_notificationstype);
```

I using spanable but didnot get result

```
Typeface  fontbold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf"); 

String[] sentence = s1.split(" ");
for(String word: sentence)
{
    if(word.contains("Good"))
    {
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(word);
        spannable.setSpan(fontbold , 0, 4, 0);
        tvnotificationstype.setText("I"+" "+"am"+" "+"a"+" "+spannable+"boy"); 
    }
}
```

I am using above code but i did not get the  custom font effect .so please help me is there any mistake the above code.advance thanks for all

Comment: Try use [CustomTypefaceSpan class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font) to change typeface of part of string.

Comment: above link worked fine but ,tvnotificationstype.setText("I"+" "+"am"+" "+"a"+" "+spannable+"boy") spannable not effect the font .this situation tvnotificationstype.setText(spannable) effect the custom font. any way thanks