# TextView different size and arrangement issue

Tags: android, uitextview, textview

**PROBLEM**

I want to make my TextView look like below pic, is it possible ?

please advice, Thank !

[image: this]

**NOTE**

when I use spannable and set ° to become small, its height is place at the middle of 20.

However, I can't make C and ° in the same vertical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990381/how-to-create-vertically-aligned-superscript-and-subscript-in-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deg_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="65sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deg_symbol"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:text="°"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deg_units"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have try your answer and adjust some, it's a bit complex but it work thank !