# Android - how to build a custom textview that has money with superscript aligned with dollar value

Tags: android, spannable

I would like to build a custom textview that can show money like this:

[image]

In the end I want any user to be able to call it like this:

```
<com.util.MyCustomViews.MoneyTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="24.92"
    android:textColor="#727272"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Two problems I have is that if I use html to achieve tis its not quite the exact height UX team wants the cents raised by. They only want the cents raised half way as you can see in the photo. so calling `<p>This text contains <sup>superscript</sup>45</p>`raises it too high.  i need to to put able to raise it myself.  Im not sure how to begin but im assuming I'll over ride setText in a custom textView like this:

```
class MoneyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public MoneyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MoneyTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MoneyTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        Spannable s = getSomeCustomSpannableSuperScriptString(getContext(), text);
        super.setText(s, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I Tried the following code but it did not work:

public class MoneyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

```
static final String SEPERATOR = ".";
static final double HEIGHT_IN_EM = 0.5;
static final int MOGO_BASELINE_SHIFT = 10;

public MoneyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MoneyTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MoneyTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {

    super.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>$27</b><sup style=\"vertical-align:top,line-height:"+HEIGHT_IN_EM+"em\">.45</sup>"), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

and used it with this constant:  static final double HEIGHT_IN_EM = 0.5;

but this is the output i get no matter the height i choose, on a nexus api 19 emulator:

[image]

it wont push down the ".45".

the layout file itself if necessary looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplicationtest.MainActivity">

    <com.example.myapplicationtest.MoneyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="666.33"
        android:textSize="22dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would go with two TextViews.

Comment: I think you need check this library to getting some idea : https://github.com/fabiomsr/MoneyTextView

Comment: Please check this out .....>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990381/how-to-create-vertically-aligned-superscript-and-subscript-in-textview

Comment: @HareshChhelana thats a good library. but its missing the ability to adjust the height of the superscript. i want to push the cents values down more or add padding to it etc.  its too high. If there was a app:decimalGravity="center" it would be nice or if there was an adjustDecimalPadding attribute. any suggestions as i really like the library otherwise. and Reaz i thought of two textviews but i want a custom component others can share.

Comment: @HareshChhelana , the library you mentioned resolved my issue. see https://github.com/fabiomsr/MoneyTextView/issues/6 .  thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the library @HareshChhelana mentioned resolved my issue.

it perfectly aligns at runtime the text. in the android viewer it was not aligning though. had to wait until runtime.

[the resolution is from here](https://github.com/fabiomsr/MoneyTextView/issues/6)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Ticker](https://github.com/robinhood/ticker). You can change the source per your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer Html.fromHtml method for displaying such type of texts. It is easier as compared to spannable string .
 Just use the following line in your textView setText method .

```
double HEIGHT_IN_EM=0.5;
```

and

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>$27</b><sup style=\"vertical-align:top,line-height:"+HEIGHT_IN_EM+"em\">.45</sup>")
```

Comment: the problem is i need to be able to adjust the height of the superscript

Comment: @j2emanue In place of line height use whatever height you want .

Comment: yes i think this can solve my problem but can you tell me if there is a way to control the size of the subscript ? lets say i wanted to lower the subscript height using line-height property you showed, how would i then make the size bigger.  is there a text size property ?

Comment: Its all  about  how well you can use HTML . Just put the $27 in bold tag .e.g. <b>$27</b> . It will make the size of subscript bigger.

Comment: hi. i tried it but the spannable will not accept the line-height. it just gets ignored. have you tried it yourself ? i even started a new project and tried it fresh but still the style properites get ignored. i am applying them to a textview. the sub tag works but not the styles. can you try it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139929/discussion-between-rishabh-maurya-and-j2emanue).

Comment: when i try your updated code the line height has no affect. it does a superscript but i can not adjust line height still. i updated my question.

Comment: It is so simple .