# Custom font for an editText selection

Tags: android, android-layout

I have checked on how to achieve this but I have not gotten the solution yet.

Scenario : I have an edit-text with a long string in it. I want to set a custom font on about 2 words in the edit-text. How do I do that please?

Comment: Is it an EditText or TextView ?

Comment: It is possible with a `SpannableString` as mentioned below, but user actions in the `EditText` may destroy the formatting.

Comment: @Stallion, Its an EdittText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SpannableString` for text customization.
Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741161/7001152