# Android - How to change bottom navigation bar text's font family

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, typeface

I have created a bottom bar navigation in my android page. But now I want to apply the custom font-family in bottom navigation texts.

This is the bottom navigation code in `.xml` file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Also, code in `bottom_navigation_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_newsfeed"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="NEWSFEED"
        />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/ic_explorer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="EXPLORER"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ic_notify"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
            android:title="NOTIFY"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ic_more"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
            android:title="MORE"
            />

</menu>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this links may help you [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942533/how-to-change-custom-font-of-android-menu-item), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077403/how-to-change-font-of-menu-item-in-android)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611619/how-to-change-navigation-drawer-font

Comment: Have you checked above links @Neha Beniwal ??

Comment: all the links above are for drawers or menu item and really relevant to the question. Don't even bother check them.

Answer (score 140):

add the font file in the res/font/ folder to bundle fonts as resources

then

You can change it using style resources.
In your styles.xml:

```
<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView" 
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it as a theme in your view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
/>
```

Just checked on my app, it works fine.

reference:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#fonts-in-code

Comment: Thanks. This answer should be marked as accepted. In my case, I am using `Calligraphy library` so my style xml was like `<item name="fontPath">fonts/lato_medium.ttf</item>`

Comment: Be aware that if you want to change your text's font you have to specify : name="fontFamily" and NOT name="android:fontFamily"

Comment: This answer works but it also overrides the default animation

Comment: For me, this answer moves the label above the icon and removes the spacing

Answer (score 56):

In your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
    ... />
```

In your styles.xml:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationViewTextStyle">
    ...
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/whatever_font</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: this is better than A. Kazarovets's answer because it doesn't override and screw with animation

Comment: FYI: This didn't work for me with android:fontFamily, only with just fontFamily (the equivalent of app:fontFamily)

Comment: Good Answer it is working with Theme.MaterialComponents style

Comment: This worked for me, without breaking animation or the text label placement

Answer (score 12):

If you have a CustomFont in "Asset Folder" and you want to set in your "Bottom Navigation" use this code

```
        public static void persian_iran_font(final Context context, final View v) {
            try {
                if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
                    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                        persian_iran_font(context, child);
                    }
                } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "teshrinarmedium.otf"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

And then use methode in your MainActivity
Like This

```
  BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
  persian_iran_font(getApplicationContext(), navigation);
```

kotlin Version

```
fun persian_iran_font(context: Context, v: View) {
    try {
        if (v is ViewGroup) {
            val vg = v as ViewGroup
            for (i in 0 until vg.childCount) {
                val child: View = vg.getChildAt(i)
                persian_iran_font(context, child)
            }
        } else if (v is TextView) {
            (v as TextView).setTypeface(
                Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    context.getAssets(),
                    "teshrinarmedium.otf"
                )
            )
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

Goodluck

Comment: why did you extends Font class from AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad we needed context and view so had to extends from AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 9):

This can be done by overriding **onLayout** method of **BottomNavigationView** class then using the extended tag. This approach also shows all menu titles and disables shifting.

```
public final class ExtendedBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView{
    private final Context context;
    private Typeface fontFace = null;

    public ExtendedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final ViewGroup bottomMenu = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
        final int bottomMenuChildCount = bottomMenu.getChildCount();
        BottomNavigationItemView item;
        View itemTitle;
        Field shiftingMode;

        if(fontFace == null){
            fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.VazirBold));
        }
        try {
            //if you want to disable shiftingMode:
            //shiftingMode is a private member variable so you have to get access to it like this:
            shiftingMode = bottomMenu.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(bottomMenu, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        for(int i=0; i<bottomMenuChildCount; i++){
            item = (BottomNavigationItemView)bottomMenu.getChildAt(i);
            //this shows all titles of items
            item.setChecked(true);
            //every BottomNavigationItemView has two children, first is an itemIcon and second is an itemTitle
            itemTitle = item.getChildAt(1);
            //every itemTitle has two children, first is a smallLabel and second is a largeLabel. these two are type of AppCompatTextView
            ((TextView)((BaselineLayout) itemTitle).getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
            ((TextView)((BaselineLayout) itemTitle).getChildAt(1)).setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<your.package.name.ExtendedBottomNavigationView android:id="@id/bottomMenu" style="@style/bottomMenu"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

**For Kotlin Lover**

Create an extension class for custom asset font

```
    /**
      * Method for Bottom Navigation Font Family
      *@param view
      *
      * */
private fun navigationTextFont(view: View) {
    if (view is ViewGroup) {
        for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
            val child = view.getChildAt(i)
            navigationTextFont(child)
        }
    } else if (view is TextView) {
        // font from asset
        view.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.assets, "fonts/roboto_bold.ttf")
        
        // Or Font From resource
        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this,R.font.roboto_bold)
    }
}
```

Now call this extension

```
   navigationTextFont(yourNavigationViewId)
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 6):

Per https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/, just set a fontFamily item for the TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption style and it’ll Just Work.  com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView will use this by default.

Just know other components that rely on TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption will get changed as well, but this might be desirable.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" parent="AppMaterialComponentsTheme">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/example</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Kotlin language:**

1: Create a file with a custom name, ex: `BottomNavigationViewExtension.kt`

2: Put the code below:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

fun BottomNavigationView.changeNavTypeface(typeface: Typeface) {
    val view: View = this
    checker(view, typeface)

}
private fun checker(view: View, typeface: Typeface) {
    if (view is ViewGroup) {
        for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
            val child = view.getChildAt(i)
            checker(child, typeface)
        }
    } else if (view is TextView) {
        view.typeface = typeface
    }
}
```

3: **Usage:**

```
navView.changeNavTypeface(
    Typeface.createFromAsset(
        assets,
        "fonts/IRANSansMobile.ttf"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void setNavigationTypeface() {
        final Typeface avenirHeavy = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "font2/Avenir-Heavy.ttf"); //replace it with your own font
        ViewGroup navigationGroup = (ViewGroup) bottomNavView.getChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < navigationGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ViewGroup navUnit = (ViewGroup) navigationGroup.getChildAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < navUnit.getChildCount(); j++) {
                View navUnitChild = navUnit.getChildAt(j);
                if (navUnitChild instanceof BaselineLayout) {
                    BaselineLayout baselineLayout = (BaselineLayout) navUnitChild;
                    for (int k = 0; k < baselineLayout.getChildCount(); k++) {
                        View baselineChild = baselineLayout.getChildAt(k);
                        if (baselineChild instanceof TextView) {
                            TextView textView = (TextView) baselineChild;
                            textView.setTypeface(avenirHeavy);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

### style.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView"
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/segoe_ui_semibold</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_bottom"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_bottom"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView" (this line)
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I am able to change the Font family & Text size without creating any classes/functions.

Add these lines to Themes.xml

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/my_bold_font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

Add `android:theme` to your BottomNavigationView.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    ... Add the line below.
    ...
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationView" />
```

Comment: material is causing problems in versions 1.8.0+

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin Code of custom BottomNavigationView to set custom font:**

1.Keep a font to assets directory of your android studio project. Here I used my font "SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf"

2.Copy below kotlin code and paste to your android studio project.

```
class FontBottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView {


constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {

}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {

}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {

}

private var fontFace: Typeface? = null

override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)

    val bottomMenu = getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    val bottomMenuChildCount: Int = bottomMenu.childCount
    var item: BottomNavigationItemView? = null
    var itemTitle: View? = null
    var shiftingMode: Field? = null

    if (fontFace == null){
        fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf") // font from assets directory
    }

    try {
        shiftingMode = bottomMenu.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode")
        shiftingMode.isAccessible = true
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(bottomMenu, false)
        shiftingMode.isAccessible = false
    } catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    for (i in 0..bottomMenuChildCount){
        try {
            item = bottomMenu.getChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView
            itemTitle = item.getChildAt(1)
            ((itemTitle as BaselineLayout).getChildAt(0) as AppCompatTextView).typeface = fontFace
            ((itemTitle as BaselineLayout).getChildAt(1) as AppCompatTextView).typeface = fontFace
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

}}
```

3.Use on xml file as like below:

```
<com.example.projectname.FontBottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

@Arash answer helped:

Answer (score 2):

Long story short :

```
/**
 * @param view The bottom navigation view to update
 * @param tf The typeface which the text should be displayed
 */
public static void setAllTypefaces(View view, Typeface tf) {
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            setAllTypefaces(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i),tf);
    } else if (view instanceof TextView) ((TextView) view).setTypeface(tf);
}
```

[image]