# set two or more typeface in textview string android

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-studio-3.0, android-typeface

I have two typeface :

```
Typeface typeface_font_arabic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
    Typeface typeface_font_number = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "aclonica.ttf");
```

how to use different typeface in string TextView android ?

**this is my code in android**

sample :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yskwA.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html

Comment: @BenP. 
I do not understand from documentation:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "SpannableString", check here:

1.[SpannableString example](http://alexandroid.net/spannablestring-example/)
2. [How set Spannable object font with custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font)