# I want to retrieve sqlite data as html in my offline android android app

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am building an offline android dictionary app and I want to make some of text bold stored in sqlite database. So how can I put html tags like for bold < b > My Text< /b > and it should show bold in my app text.

Comment: You do not have to do this . Use `SpanableString` with `TypefaceSpan` during setting text . You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font .

Comment: Just save words as normal text and use the Solution above . It will provide you the flexibility for any changes in future.