# Android TypefaceSpan NoSuchMethodError for new TypefaceSpan(Typeface)

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I am working on applying a custom font on `TextView` from a library and font file is stored in res/font of the app folder.

I got the typeface by using

```
int id = context.getResources.getIdentifier("xxx","font",packageName);
Typeface typeface = context.getResources.getFont(id);
```

Typeface is not null, I have put debug points and verified.

```
TypefaceSpan span = new TypefaceSpan(typeface);
```

Now I want to create TypefaceSpan object from this typeface and I am getting below error and application crashes.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method
>   (Landroid/graphics/Typeface;)V in class
>   Landroid/text/style/TypefaceSpan; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'android.text.style.TypefaceSpan' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex).

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same exception, but in case your are supporting versions below 26 you need to use this, `ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.font_name)` instead of `context.getResources.getFont(id)`. BTW, This is not a solution for your issue.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741161/4043944) works for me

You need to create `CustomTypefaceSpan` class

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

   private final Typeface newType;

   public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
     super(family);
     newType = type;
   }

   @Override
   public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
     applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
   }

   @Override
   public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
     applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
   }

   private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
     int oldStyle;
     Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
     if (old == null) {
       oldStyle = 0;
     } else {
       oldStyle = old.getStyle();
     }

     int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
     if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
       paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
     }

     if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
       paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
     }

     paint.setTypeface(tf);
   }
 }
```

Then use it like this

```
TypeFace face = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.font_name); // in case you want to support below API 26.
new CustomTypefaceSpan("", face);
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to reproduce your code, I got these errors:  
For `getFont()`

> Call requires API level 26

For `TypefaceSpan span = new TypefaceSpan(typeface);`

> Call requires API level 27

You must have at least these in gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```