# how to use custom font style on string without any TextView on android

Tags: java, android

I am using library which do not have custom font change's option. How I can save value in string and change its font and then use this string. I do a lot of search but can not find any way without `TextView`, because I do not need any `TextView`.

```
TextView reg = findViewById(R.id.register);
FloatingActionMenu fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionMenu);

ShowcaseConfig config = new ShowcaseConfig();
config.setDelay(500);

MaterialShowcaseSequence sequence = new MaterialShowcaseSequence(this, "221");

sequence.addSequenceItem(
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(reg)
                .setContentText("I want to use custom font on this string")
                .setDismissOnTouch(true)
                .setShape(new RectangleShape(100,50))
                .build()
);
sequence.addSequenceItem(
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(fab)
                .setDismissOnTouch(true)
                .setContentText("I want to use custom font on this string")
                .build()
);
sequence.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change font color by using `CDATA` in string.xml.

```
<string name="lable_testing">"You can change font color like this "<![CDATA[<font color="%1$s">hello</font>]]></string>
```

Comment: I don't want to change color, As I mentioned on title I want to use custom fonts style.

Comment: In order to custom fonts style. First of all, you have to download another fonts style. Then set font style programmatically

Comment: There are many way that you can change font style. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font

https://proandroiddev.com/font-typeface-in-android-application-572766edddd6

Answer (score 0):

1- do you try to download library and include that library to app using include and then change the style in that library

2- do you try to add custom style with all you need include font family and add that style in xml

Comment: How to do second approach. Mean to say, How to use font family in xml. Because this library do not work in xml layout. All working is in java.

Comment: i don't use that library so i thought it added in xml as tag

Comment: No, I mentioned on question that it is in java.

Comment: so do the first option download it and change all what you need in library folder that will find xml file for design

Comment: post xml from library file and we will help you with it

Comment: https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView thats the library and its not enough Xml files. Mostly data is in java format.