# How to make Notification title bold in NotificationCompat

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have used MediaSessionCompat for generating media controls in notification by following link

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html

Here the issue is i need to make title text to be bold with custom fonts.

i have tried using Html.fromHtml() but this gives heavy bold text in title which i dont want

This is what i want

[Spotify media control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRxVu.png)

What i am getting here is

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ60J.png)

I want title "No Excuses" to same like spotify's "Lose somebody"

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/15468/android-notification-styling

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's better use InboxStyle than HTML parts.

Spannable sb = new SpannableString("Bold text");
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder()
.setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
.setContentText(subject)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
.setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
.setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
.addLine(str1)
.addLine(sb);
.setContentTitle("")
.setSummaryText("+3 more"))
.build();

Comment: How to use custom font here?

Comment: Please check this link, hope you get the idea , how use custom font.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font#:~:text=Use%20in%20the%20same%20way,custom_fonts)%3B%20Typeface%20font%20%3D%20Typeface.

Comment: This is not working with notifiction title