# TextAppearanceSpan with custom fonts

Tags: android, fonts

Is it possible to create a TextAppearanceSpan, which takes font family name as String, but use a custom font. I know how to create a TypeFace from a file with Typeface.createFromAsset(), but it isn't helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People seem to still have trouble with this so here you go:
[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface) how it was accomplished for TypefaceSpan, overriding for TextAppearanceSpan is just a tad more code.