# font management

Tags: android, textview

I use `Html.fromHtml()` in my application to display bold and regular characters in the same TextView. But I have 3 different fonts for italic,bold and regular text, and I don't know how to indicate to my text view to use one or the other.

Please give me any reference or hint.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a WebView?

Comment: @renaud :use `SpannableString` for making string with different fonts and then add to textview

Answer (score 0):

if I have not misunderstood you can format a single string with different `<font>` tag.

For instance :

```
String toShow = <font: italic ...>italic string</font> <font: bold ...>bold string</font>
Html.fromHtml(toShow)
```

choose the tag html more appropriate for this purpose. [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) is a list of supporte html tag.

edit: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_fonts.asp) an example of the html font tag. As alternative I **think** you can use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)  for the same purpose.

Comment: yes i'm sorry i don't speak very well english and you probably have misunderstood me. I know how to display some text in bold and some other in italic or standar in the same textview. but I don't know how to set a specific font for the bold text and some other for regular one. 

My problem is that i have Helvetica in 8 differents .otf and not in a single .dfont. so when i set to my text view a font, it tries by itself to build the bold and italic and it does't look good at all

Comment: I think you have to go through with the SpannableString/SpanStyle pair. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface

Comment: the problem is that i'm doing that at the end of a very long project i have to change all the font and i don't want to change every textView, i'm thinking about changing the style of the application, and doing my font thing in a style.xml file

Comment: I do not understand what you need to achieve? in a single textview you want to set a string. in this string some words have a font e some other words have another font?

Comment: i need all the bold text in my app to be in a specific font and all the standard text in my app to be in an other