# Use different typefaces for the same TextView with HTL formatting

Tags: android, html, typeface

I already know how to specify a custom typeface for my TextView. As of now, my application is using one custom font, which is splitted in two ttf files. One for regular characters and an toher one for bold characters.

Now, I would like to be able to use both inone TextView like we do with Html.fromHtml(). As it works with system fonts, it should be able to do it with my own typeface. Currently, bold characters are drawn with regular font and fake bold text for the text paint which is quite ugly.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use multiple custom fonts within a single TextView:

### Use the following code:(I'm using Bangla and Tamil font)

```
  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_fonts);  
        txt.setTextSize(30);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Akshar.ttf");
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bangla.ttf");   
        SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("আমারநல்வரவு");
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font2), 0, 4,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 4, 11,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        txt.setText(SS);
```

---

The outcome is:

[image]

---

### CustomTypefaceSpan Class:

```
package my.app;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

private final Typeface newType;

public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}

private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }

    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
}
```

---

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface)