# How can I add big AND small letters in a TextView like in the Android Dialer app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-dialer

How can I add big **AND** small letters in a TextView like in the image below:

**Sorry: "nuber" = "number"**

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe highlight which letters a bit more?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001374/how-to-use-two-different-font-sizes-for-button-text-in-android

Comment: @SuperThomasLab does it have to be a `button` view? Why not use custom `View` with background and 2 `textview` fields?

Comment: @poss I want to make a custom dialer so i put buttons in a gridlayout. but i want the buttons to be like the image attached.

Comment: You can put views in `gridlayout` and call `onClick` on them as well

Comment: @poss so i need to make a custom view for each button?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab don't use Button at all. Create own `View` with 2 `TextView` inside it and place those on a grid. Similar approach like in  @TechnoBlahble link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the button you see in the UI isn't a standard Android Button, but rather a composite View made up of two TextViews.

You should make sure that your composite View is focusable and clickable, (not the two TextViews that its made of) and provide default, focus and pressed states for this View.

```
public class MyCompositeView extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView primaryTextView;
    private TextView secondaryTextView;

    public MyCompositeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        super.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    }

    @Override
    public final void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        if (orientation != HORIZONTAL) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("MyCompositeView is a button-like widget, not a ViewGroup! Don't change my orientation");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.merge_my_composite_view, this);
        primaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_composite_text_primary);
        secondaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_composite_text_secondary);
    }

    public void setPrimaryText(String text) {
        if (valid(text)) {
            primaryTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        } else {
            primaryTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        primaryTextView.setText(text);
    }

    private static boolean valid(String text) {
        return text != null && !text.trim().isEmpty();
    }

    public void setSecondaryText(String text) {
        if (valid(text)) {
            secondaryTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        } else {
            secondaryTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        secondaryTextView.setText(text);
    }

}
```

The merge layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_composite_text_primary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_composite_text_secondary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />

</merge>
```

And you would use it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.MyCompositeView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use  `Html.fromHtml` as:

```
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("html_code_with"));
```

instead of html_code_with set your html code for big text and small text.

Comment: Could you give me a small sample of what i want

Comment: button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>BIG</h1>small"));

Comment: ok, the Html.fromHtml(StringHtmlValue) allow to transform a simple String to a android Html compatible String.
so, if you set your button text as button.setText(Html.fromHtml(myStringButtonText));
and that, myStringButtonText as "<h1>"+bigValu+"</h1>"+smallValue;
on your Button, android will display the myStringButtonText like a web navigator.
in Html language, Tag <H1> allow render a big text
please try this on your button and look result.