# Custom Textview with Html text and Custom Font whole Android application

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have created a custom textview to set the custom font and to set the html text for whole application. Because my app has both the functions in many places. In this case, i can able to set the custom font to whole android application it works great. but failed to apply html text for custom textview.

Limitations i have:

1. I do not want to get the textview and use `setText(Html.fromHtml("Some text"))`. It is working when i using this in code but i want to use the text in `strings.xml` as `<string name="my_app"><![CDATA[My Whole <b>app</b>lication]]></string>`
2. I cannot override settext in custom class function since it is final method.
3. I have the html text nearly 100. I do not want to hard code this strings in code. Please help.

My custom class:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/gothic.ttf"));
    }
}
```

My layout file:

```
<com.views.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_app" />
```

I get the output as : My application

I want the output as: My **app**lication

app in bold text

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consideret to use SpannbleString?
[How can I use TypefaceSpan or StyleSpan with a custom Typeface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-custom-typeface)

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html) is different spans that you can apply on SpannableString.

```
 public void setSpan(){
    Spannable spantext = new SpannableString("My application");


    spantext.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 3//Start of span, 6//End of span, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    Typeface HelveticaNeueBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueBoldItalic.ttf");
    spantext.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", HelveticaNeueBoldItalic ), 0, text.lenght(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);



    TextView text;

    text.setText(spantext);
}






 public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {
        private final Typeface newType;

        public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
            super(family);
            newType = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
            applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
        }

        private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
            int oldStyle;
            Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
            if (old == null) {
                oldStyle = 0;
            } else {
                oldStyle = old.getStyle();
            }

            int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
            if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
                paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
            }

            if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
                paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
            }

            paint.setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply user1888162. But how can i use this in custom text view. So that i can use this in whole application. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I used this spannable string in custom view constructor. it works great.