# Set text of a textview with different sizes

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView and I want each word of the text to be with different size and font.

I know that you can set part of the text to be bold or with underline with the  and  tags.

But what if I need part of the text to be the size of 18sp and have a custom typeface(from assets) and another part to have a different custom typeface and a size of 14sp.

**I can split the TextView to individual TextViews, but I want to avoid that.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `RelativeSizeSpan` ,for Reference [RelativeSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html) for different font sizes.

```
TextView tv;
final SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello World");
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f), 0, 5,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 5, 11,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(text);
```

For FontStyle use `StyleSpan` for reference [StyleSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html)

So use can use `custom typeface` with the help of **StyleSpan**.

```
text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), start,
                    end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I used AbsoluteSizeSpan as you can set the text size in px, rather than RelativeSizeSpan which sets the proportion of text size.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in HTML with all the styling you like and then use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) in the `setText()` method:

**E.g.:**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

**Or:**

Refer to this question. it might help you:
[Custom Textview with Html text and Custom Font whole Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321614/custom-textview-with-html-text-and-custom-font-whole-android-application)

Comment: And what if I want to use a custom typeface from the assets ?