# How to Set Custom Font for Action bar or Activity title Android?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I am trying to change font for Activity title, but its not working. Please suggest? I am trying like this

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("LOGIN");
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
s.setSpan(tf, 0, s.length(),
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked a very long time ago, but this might help others.
Apparently, you can't use the typeface object as an input to the setSpan method, although it does take an Object as its first argument (and everything is an Object), but to set a custom font the first argument needs to be TypefaceSpan object:

```
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(***), 0, s.length, flag); // whatever flag you are using
```

The problem is, TypefaceSpan takes either a String or a Parcelable, not a typeface object, so as far as I understand, you can't set a custom font that is created from an asset for example. 
This is where I am stuck actually because I am looking for a solution for this rather than the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface) by "notme" which is extending TypefaceSpan object, although it probably works but I am looking for a more simpler and elegant way to do this.

Good luck and happy coding.