# Custom font in android action bar without making custom Actionbar

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-actionbar-compat

My question is i want to change font of action bar without making custom layout for action bar like implment text view and then apply typeface on that text view because i want to too subtitle bar text so what is solution for it

Comment: Do you want to change the  font of only the title?

Comment: i want to set font on title and subtitle too..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following code in `onCreate()`

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
            "android");
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    txtTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));
    txtTitle.setTypeface((Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"FuturaBoldBT.ttf")));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Using `getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android")` is a bad way to do it.

Comment: @Pranav Because `action_bar_title` is a private id.

Comment: thats ryt but, there are not any solution for set custom font on actionbar title

Comment: @Pranav I gave you one. The idea is to set a "decorated" String (aka `SpannableString`) instead of a String. It works with setTitle and setSubtitle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpannableString` with a custom TypeFaceSpan (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826885/1785133) for actionBar title and subtitle.

```
SpannableString sbTitle = new SpannableString(getTitle());
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "custom.ttf"); //cache it
sbTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("custom", typeface), 0, sbTitle.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
getActionBar().setTitle(sbTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
SpannableString localSpannableString = new SpannableString("Penguin");
localSpannableString.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(MainActivity.this, "PreludeFLF-BoldItalic.ttf"), 0, localSpannableString.length(), 33);

ActionBar localActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
localActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#81D2F0")));
localActionBar.setTitle(localSpannableString);
```

Comment: where font file put..?

Comment: In `assets` folder in your project