# Make TextView use a custom typeface with different styles (regular and italic)

Tags: android, html, textview, typeface

I have a TextView and I need to display the following string on it: "Some *text*". And I want the TextView to use a custom font for this. So I need to get the following output: [image]

I tried the following code:

```
    textView.setText("some <i>text</i>");
    final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "customfont-regular.otf");
    if (typeface != null)
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

But the result was: [image], so the Italic is actually fake, generated by the system. Then I tried the following:

```
    textView.setText("some <i>text</i>");
    final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "customfont-regular.otf");
    if (typeface != null)
        textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
    final Typeface typefaceItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "customfont-italic.otf");
    if (typefaceItalic != null)
        textView.setTypeface(typefaceItalic, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

But the output was all-italic! [image]

So how can I combine custom typefaces for regular and italic in a single TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the following solution for this:

```
    final Typeface typefaceItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "customfont-italic.otf");

    // there is no easy way in Android to make a single TextView display text using custom typeface with different styles (regular and italic). We need to replace all Italic spans with custom typeface spans for this.
    final SpannableString text = new SpannableString("some <i>text</i>");
    final StyleSpan[] spans = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), StyleSpan.class);
    for (StyleSpan span : spans) {
        if (span.getStyle() == Typeface.ITALIC) {
            text.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("customfont", italicTypeface), text.getSpanStart(span), text.getSpanEnd(span), 0);
            text.removeSpan(span);
        }
    }
    textView.setText(text);

    final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "customfont-regular.otf");
    if (typeface != null)
        textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

`CustomTypefaceSpan` is a class described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826885/190148