# Custom Typeface Span not working

Tags: android, text, typeface

I am trying to use [Custom Typeface Span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface) in my application but it doesn't working. Here is my code

```
Typeface font3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"); 
SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("&#xf17b;");
SS.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font3), 0, 8,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(SS);
```

Here I am trying to use [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in Custom Typeface Span.

Comment: there is no such class CustomTypefaceSpan in the android sdk

Comment: FYI: I have used CustomTypefaceSpan from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface

Comment: What ever happened here? I'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687205/font-awesome-in-viewpager-previous-next

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom TypefaceSpan and then you can use it anywhere to apply font style in any place.
Create a class TypefaceSpan as mentioned below.

```
   public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
/** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
        new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

private Typeface mTypeface;

/**
 * Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a {@link android.text.Spannable}.
 */
public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
    mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

    if (mTypeface == null) {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                .getAssets(), typefaceName);//String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

        // Cache the loaded Typeface
        sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
    }
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
    p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

    // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
    p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
    tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

    tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
}
```

and then you can use this class for applying font styles. 
Example--

```
actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Hostel-16");
    s.setSpan(new com.example.suraj.hostel16.TypefaceSpan(getApplicationContext(),"georgia.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
```