# Android Font in more than one language on single screen

Tags: android, fonts, arabic-support

I am new to Android. And I am implementing an application which will be in two languages English and Urdu. Basically there will be some text in arabic and its meaning will be in english or urdu based on the user selected language.

I want to change the font of arabic text, If I apply font in whole application it will change the look of Urdu and English also. So is this will be fine to just apply font to each textview that contains arabic fonts using TypeFace or there is some better way to achieve this?

And also I want to know how to remove custom fonts in order to get default font back again through code. I just want to know what are the possibilities to do this.

Answer (score 1):

for example if you want your application to support both English
and Arabic strings (in addition to the default strings), 
you can simply create two additional
resource directories called `/res/values-en` (for the English strings.xml) and
`/res/values-ar` (for the Arabic strings.xml).

Within the `strings.xml` files, the
resource names are the same.

For example, the `/res/values-en/strings.xml` file could
look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello in English!</string>
</resources>
```

Whereas, the /res/values-ar/strings.xml file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">مرحبا في اللغة الإنجليزية</string>
</resources>
```

also , the /res/values-ur_IN/strings.xml file would look like this for urdu:

ur_IN for india  ur_PK for pakisthan

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">انگریزی میں خوش!!</string>
</resources>
```

A default layout file in the /res/layout directory that displays the string refers to the
string by the variable name @string/hello, without regard to which language or directory
the string resource is in.

The Android operating system determines which version of
the string (French, English, or default) to load at runtime.A layout with a TextView control
to display the string might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/hello" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The string is accessed programmatically in the normal way:

```
String str = getString(R.string.hello);
```

For change the language you need to like that change lang..

```
btn_english.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("en"); 
                  Locale.setDefault(locale);
                  Configuration config = new Configuration();
                  config.locale = locale;
                  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                  Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_langSelectEnglis), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



 btn_arbice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Locale locale = new Locale("ar"); 
                  Locale.setDefault(locale);
                  Configuration config = new Configuration();
                  config.locale = locale;
                  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                  Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_langSelecURdu), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


 btn_urdu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("ur_IN"); 
                  Locale.setDefault(locale);
                  Configuration config = new Configuration();
                  config.locale = locale;
                  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                  Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_langSelectEnglis), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Also see this example for single screen

[Custom fonts for TextView based on languages inside String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903712/custom-fonts-for-textview-based-on-languages-inside-string)

String paragraph = "hey what's up ضعيف";
    int NO_FLAG = 0;
    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(paragraph, NO_FLAG);
    int runCount = bidi.getRunCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
        String ltrtl = bidi.getRunLevel(i) % 2 == 0 ? "ltr" : "rtl";
        String subString = paragraph.substring(bidi.getRunStart(i), bidi.getRunLimit(i));
        Log.d(">>bidi:" + i,  subString+" is "+ltrtl);
    }

prints:

> hey what's up  is ltr
>
> ضعيف is rtl

So now one can easily build `TypefaceSpan` or `MetricAffectingSpan` based on language direction like this:

```
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(paragraph);
for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
    Object span = bidi.getRunLevel(i) % 2 == 0 ? ltrFontSpan : rtlFontSpan;
    spanString.setSpan(span, bidi.getRunStart(i), bidi.getRunLimit(i), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
}
textView.setText(spanString);
```