# How to apply RTL dynamically and effectively

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, right-to-left

I'm creating and adding TextViews in linear layout dynamically, whenever I'm applying `layoutAmount.setRotationY(180);` the layout changes its direction which is right, but the words of TextViews inside it also changes direction which is wrong, for example, if the word is sorry its becomes yrros, how can I apply RTL correctly

Thanks!

Comment: Did you want the layout rotation for RTL like for Arabic layout

Comment: yes RTL for arabic

Comment: apply my answer, let me know if its work or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**setLayoutDirection** will set layout direction according to the language

-Make sure that use layout gravity start and end

```
 public static void setLanguage(Context context, String language) {
            String[] localeLang = language.split("_");
            Locale locale;
            if (localeLang.length > 1)
                locale = new Locale(localeLang[0], localeLang[1]);
            else
                locale = new Locale(localeLang[0]);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
                ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(config.getLayoutDirection());
            }
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to make layout dynamic RTL by following,

If you use ConstraintLayout

Don't use `left and right`

instead, use `start and end`

Android will change layout dynamically when you change locale

> You can find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49423631/6299045) about how to change the language of the app by locale

Update:

In ConstraintLayout 
Use Constrains as

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_about_back"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Also, don't use margin left or right

In case of LinearLayout,

> use `gravity start and end`

sample code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="@string/about_al_ameen"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @blackHawk i update answer , also sample linear layout with text view

Answer (score 1):

when you choose language add;

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(LAngSelect.this, "ar");
```

Then save it with sqlite or other.

Then go to MainActivity with intent:

on MainActivity get the language saved and add:

```
if (langs.equals("ar")) {
                    forceRTLIfSupported();
                }

    private void forceRTLIfSupported()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){

            //HERE CHECK CONDITION FOR YOUR LANGUAGE if it is AR then
            //change if it is english then don't

            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);


        }
    }
```