# Not loading string from correct resource in multi language application

Tags: java, android, multilingual

I want to add Persian language to my application . i made a new string.xml file as 'fa' and set translated text there by using the following function I have tried to change the language of application :

```
    public void loadLanguage() {
    Locale locale = new Locale(manager.getAppLanguage());
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration cong = new Configuration();
    cong.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(cong , getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

I call this function before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in my MainActivity .

after I run the application and change language to Persian everything change to RTL correctly but still string loaded from English resource and all text still are English.

Does anybody have an idea about why this happened ??

Comment: Please make sure that your newly created **String.xml** contains the particular languages string

Comment: i am sure .even i put Persian language in difficult string.xml but it still load string from English resource . @MittalVarsani

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983869/6908588

Comment: supporting rtl is not my problem . my question is why persian resources not use when i set language to persian ? @MittalVarsani

Comment: You will need to recreate the activity in order to change the language
otherwise, it will update the UI and not change the language