# Xamarin AppCompat textview custom

Tags: android, xamarin, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-appcompat

After updating Android Support Libary v7 AppCompat 
I'm not able to change style to the title and the following 
is not wotking anymore:

```
int myTitleId = Resources.GetIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView barTitle = FindViewById<TextView>(myTitleId);
barTitle.SetTypeface(FontFactory.GetMyFont(this), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After integrating the new Toolbar this is how I changed style.

inside **protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)** of my Activity (that now extends **AppCompatActivity**)
where before there was the previous code now I have:

```
toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

var f = toolbar.Class.GetDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
f.Accessible = true;
var barTitle  = (TextView)f.Get(toolbar);
barTitle.SetTypeface(FontFactory.GetMyFont(this), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

I needed also to add this on the top:

```
using Java.Lang; //for the reflection
using Toolbar =  Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
```

and in the layout.axml I included the toolbar.axml in this way:

```
//...
<include
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
layout="@layout/toolbar" /> 
//...
```

Comment: FWIW: this approach is just a wonky as your original one. While things may work for now, it's guaranteed to break as soon as the Android team decides to rename the `mTitleTextView` field, move it to some sort of delegate, or remove it altogether. You *shouldn't* be relying on the framework's internal implementation details, especially in production code. I would strongly recommend a more robust approach if you don't want to run into the same issue again a few updates down the road.

Answer (score 0):

That's because AppCompat now uses a `ToolBar` widget as replacement for ActionBar. `ToolBar` creates a `TextView` instance for the title on-the-fly; if you dig into the `(android.support.v7.widget.)ToolBar` code, you'll find something like this:

```
mTitleTextView = new TextView(context);
```

(Refer to line 607 of `android.support.v7.widget.ToolBar` in `appcompat-v7-23.0.1-sources.jar`)

More importantly, no id is ever assigned to the view. This can also easily be seen by inspecting the view hierarchy:

[image]

That `TextView` that you see is the one that holds the title. The id is a generated value and not predefined (like i.e. the one for the `ActionBarContainer`), which means you can no longer look it up through some sort of static reference.

That explains why your code, which does an id-lookup-by-name, no longer works: the `action_bar_title` id is simply no longer being used here.

There are several solutions to make setting a custom font to the ActionBar title work again. The cleanest is probably to leverage the fact that [`setTitle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)) takes a `CharSequence`, which means you can attach a [custom typeface span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface) to it that enables the custom font and/or style to work. Doing this is some sort of a 'base' `Activity` would probably make most sense.

You can of course also iterate over the local view hierarchy, starting at `ToolBar`, but I'd say that's not quite as robust and prone to suffer from future changes (like your current code ;)).

Alternatively, consider using a library to simplify dealing with applying custom fonts. [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) is usually my first stop for this.